# Which packages contains the strings present on login screen?

Tags: login-screen

I'm asking this because I contribute to translations on Launchpad and I need to test them.

I have translated respective strings for words like 'Password' and 'Not listed?' from the **gnome-shell** package but they still appear in English on login screen. `LC_` and `LANG` environment variables are set to target language and applied system-wide.

I'm wondering if there's some other program built on top of gnome-shell that has those strings. If gdm3 isn't the one, what is then?

Answer (score 0):

On Debian it is `gnome-shell` package. See below links for details:

- https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=Not+listed%3F&literal=1
- https://sources.debian.org/src/gnome-shell/3.38.6-1/js/gdm/loginDialog.js/?hl=456#L456
- https://sources.debian.org/src/gnome-shell/3.38.6-1/po/en_GB.po/#L453

You have to find similar for Ubuntu.

Comment: Those links were very helpful in the sense that I didn't know Debian had such an amazing tool! Unfortunately, they didn't help me get closer to solving my issue. Translating those strings from gnome-shell yields no results as they still appear in English. 

Thank you nonetheless!